# Visual studio 2015 Xaml error does not make sense

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I am very new to WPF programming, so please forgive if this is an obvious mistake on my part.  I have a UserControl object that has the following Xaml:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="SDMAS.LOOPAnalyzer.Views.Workspace"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDMAS.LOOPAnalyzer.Models" >

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- create an instance of our DataProvider class -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="tblLOOPDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:tblLOOPDataProvider}"/>
    <!-- define the method which is invoked to obtain our data -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="LOOPEvents" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource tblLOOPDataProvider}" MethodName="GetData"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource LOOPEvents}}">
    <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGrid"/>
  </DockPanel>

    </UserControl>
```

This code actually works.  The records from the data table are correctly displayed in the application's view.   The problem is the Visual Studio designer for this control thinks there is a problem, complaining about not being able to find the object type in the namespace: ObjectType="{x:Type local:tblLOOPDataProvider}"

The namespace does exist, and does contain the class, as proven by the fact the code is working.  So what gives with the designer?

The following is screenshot of the error message:

[image: Screenshot showing VS complaint]

Here is the tblLOOPDataProvider code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SDMAS.LOOPAnalyzer.Models.LOOPDataSetTableAdapters;

namespace SDMAS.LOOPAnalyzer.Models
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Provides a singleton instance of the LOOPDataSet
  /// </summary>
  public class LOOPDataProvider
  {
    private static LOOPDataSet _loopDataSet;

    public static LOOPDataSet LOOPDataSet
    {
      get
      {
        if (_loopDataSet == null)
        {
          _loopDataSet = new LOOPDataSet();
        }
        return _loopDataSet;
      }
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// A source of LOOP event objects
  /// </summary>
  public class tblLOOPDataProvider
  {
    private tblLOOPTableAdapter _adapter;

    public tblLOOPDataProvider()
    {
      LOOPDataSet dataset = LOOPDataProvider.LOOPDataSet;

      _adapter = new tblLOOPTableAdapter();
      _adapter.Fill(LOOPDataProvider.LOOPDataSet.tblLOOP);

      dataset.tblLOOP.tblLOOPRowChanged += new LOOPDataSet.tblLOOPRowChangeEventHandler(tblLOOPRowModified);
      dataset.tblLOOP.tblLOOPRowDeleted += new LOOPDataSet.tblLOOPRowChangeEventHandler(tblLOOPRowModified);
    }

    void tblLOOPRowModified(object sender, LOOPDataSet.tblLOOPRowChangeEvent e)
    {
      _adapter.Update(LOOPDataProvider.LOOPDataSet.tblLOOP);
    }

    public DataView GetData()
    {
      return LOOPDataProvider.LOOPDataSet.tblLOOP.DefaultView;
    }

  }
}
```

Since I first posted this I have been hacking at various parts of the project, and now the designer won't display the Xaml at all.  Just says Loading Designer... and appears to hang.

Some more background.  I started this project based on the Prism4Demo on CodeProject (by David Veeneman). It has changed much since it's beginning, migrating to Prism 6 and updating other dependencies.  That demo seemed a good template for an application that will have a number of modules to be developed independently by different staff members, likely with only one professional programmer to provide integration (not me).   The class creating the designer problem is the "workspace" view for one of the modules that will eventually be wired to a view-model that in turn will be wired to a model consisting of a DataSet representing a LOOP event data table on a SQL server.  In this current learning step, I have connected the server data table to a DataSet, which I am displaying in the workspace view directly without the view-model in the middle (and it is working, aside from the designer issue).  I have based the code on internet examples that I don't yet understand all the way, but have been able to make work.  So I don't yet understand the reason for the LOOPDataProvider class complexity, or the use of Resources in the Xaml.

So I continue to study the MVVM structure and my next step will be to wire up the DataSet-based model to the view-model, and the view-model to the view.

Comment: Does the error still happen after rebuilding the project?

Comment: Yes, rebuilding does not affect the error

Comment: Does tblLOOPDataProvider have default constructor? The one without parameter?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the tblLOOPDataProvider?

I'm not familiar with "ObjectDataProvider" but when I see you ItemsSource binding I would expect it to be bound to the property of a ViewModel.

Could you share more of your code so we can see why you're not using a ViewModel etc. ?

Comment: Normally when I get issues like this with the designer in both WPF and silverlight I would delete the *obj* folder and rebuild the project. Some quirk with visual studio I guess. Works for me 90% of the time.

Comment: Often the problem is that objects are created in the xaml or the code behind that are not supported in the designer. Make sure no file or db operations are performed in the xaml or ctor.

Comment: @JohnSchroeder, I think @Wouter may be on to something. If you are indeed making a file or db op in `tblLOOPDataProvider` ctor, then you need to make sure your object is aware of if it is being created at design time or run time.

Comment: Ok, That may be the problem,  When I wired the data provider to the view model, and the view model into the view, no more problem.  Although from your explanation, It sounds like I should have been able to make this work with some modification to my data provider constructor?